# How is the Transaction ID generated in Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

How is the transaction ID generated in Hyperledger Fabric at the time of adding a block into the chain and how is it different from the block hash?

Also, is there an option to view the previous and current block hash for each block both in local fabric setup (first network setup in Ubuntu) as well as IBM Blockchain starter plan?

Answer (score 2):

This should probably be two separate questions. I can answer the first.

It's a hash of a Nonce and the user credentials creating the transaction. It is generated by the client creating the proposals that get send to peers to execute the transaction.

For example in [fabric-sdk-go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/36698e6d682b220fcd92b43560c3d719e9e984c6/pkg/fab/txn/env.go#L54-L100).